# Bind default value to TextBoxFor in MVC not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

When I bind default value to textboxfor but it's not working as expected

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LinkAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @Value = ViewBag.link })
```

ViewBag.link  is value that pass from controller

I wanna set ViewBag.link value as default value of textboxfor but it's not working as expected

Comment: Never attempt to set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods. You set the value of `LinkAddress` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view (that is how model binding works - it binds to the model)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Model you don't need a ViewBag because the value from Model property will bind to the TextBoxFor.
But if you use just TextBox you must do it in 2 ways

First:

```
@Html.TextBox("LinkAddress", (String)ViewBag.link)
```

Second:

```
<input type="text" value="@ViewBag.link" />
```

Comment: You first option doe not work (the 2nd parameter if for html attributes), and the 2nd option is terrible advice

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LinkAddress, new {  @Value = @ViewBag.link })
```

Or

```
@Html.TextBox("LinkAddress", null, new { @Value = @ViewBag.link })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `value` attribute assignment with `ViewBag` is pointless, because `TextBoxFor` is already bound to your viewmodel and you can simply assign it from a controller action which returns view using GET method (`[HttpGet]`) with corresponding viewmodel:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
    var model = new ViewModel();
    model.LinkAddress = "linkaddresshere";

    return View(model);
}
```

And leave `TextBoxFor` as-is:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LinkAddress)
```

If you want to assign textbox helper's value from client-side, use `jQuery.val()` or `value` property from vanilla JS *after the DOM objects are fully loaded*:

```
// jQuery
$('#LinkAddress').val("linkaddresshere");

// vanilla JS
document.getElementById('LinkAddress').value = "linkaddresshere";
```